# Can we use slicing in list pop ( ) ? the answer is yes? tell how?

Tags: python

I need to know that can we just pop every string literal from the list using slicing in pop function ?

Comment: No, you can't. Pop() function takes only integer not a slice.

Comment: Yeah tk u but we can use del ( ) to do it

Comment: You would usually use a list comprehension with a condition to filter the items.

Comment: You can do everything, just not with built-in JS .pop() as said @Marceline

Answer (score -1):

Sorry ,posting question and finding solution after some time is good but now it is awkward . So the answer is we can use del ( ) to use slicing and thats it .bye